# How to create an website with Unity smooth?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, unity-game-engine

I am quite curious about this website that I just found.

https://jenamdvacet.cz/

From its code, it is created with Unity.
but it is so smoothly transit between a "normal" website and Unity assets.

Please, break down how to create this type of website with Unity and explain what type of languages used and published.

Thank you!

Comment: as far as I can tell this is just a faded overlay .. waiting for a certain [call from Unity to JavaScript](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) to tell it that loading is done and it can trigger the fading ... or maybe there is even something on the JS side .. not sure about that one

Answer (score 0):

website uses communication between browser and unity instance(canvas) via javasript. For more informations you can read unity3d webgl documentation.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

For communication from unity instance to browser you can use access to window object. For example I'am using EventListener to catch events.

For run functions inside unity instance you can call it as a SendMessage function and pass object name, function name and antributes. For example

`unityInstance.SendMessage('MyGameObject', 'MyFunction', 'MyString');`